# When returning a function with a passed parameter, how does the parameter get stored?

Tags: r

Below is a contrived example of passing a parameter to a returned function. I would like to have the returned function evaluate param to 2, and in fact, that's what it does!!

However, how does this work? When I print the function, it shows "param" and not "2". But when I `debug()`, I confirm that param is in fact 2.

```
f <- function(x, param = 2) {      
  my_cdf <- ecdf(x)      
  function(new_x) {
      my_cdf(new_x) * param
  }
}

g <- f(1:10)
g

# > function(new_x) {
# >   my_cdf(new_x) * param
# > }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `param` is not defined in the function in which it is used, `param` is looked up in the environment in wihch the function that uses it was *defined* and param = 2 in that environment. This is referred to as lexical scoping.

If you want to have `param` actually substituted into the function then try `substitute` like this:

```
f <- function(x, param = 2) {      
  my_cdf <- ecdf(x)   
  F <- function(new, x)
      my_cdf(new_x) * param
  body(F) <- do.call("substitute", list(body(F), list(param = param)))
  F
}
f(1:10)
```

Comment: I made a correction to my question by showing the returned function, but you answer still applies. I originally tried to get $param$ to be evaluated so that when inspecting $g$, it would show 2 instead. Since everything works, it's more moot at this point.

Comment: OK. Have added an example of actually substituting `param` in.

Answer (score 0):

This [chapter](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html#closures) from Advanced R has greater detail on what is happening.

A few examples from that chapter:

```
as.list(environment(g))

# $my_cdf
# Empirical CDF 
# Call: ecdf(x)
#  x[1:10] =      1,      2,      3,  ...,      9,     10
# 
# $x
#  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
# 
# $param
# [1] 2

library(pryr)
unenclose(g)

# function (new_x) 
# {
#     (function (v) 
#     .approxfun(x, y, v, method, yleft, yright, f))(new_x) * 2
# }
```